# How to set maximum thread level in django-threadedcomments?

Tags: django, django-comments

Is it possible to configure maximum comment thread depth? If not then how to set this limit in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I have obtained the effect using just CSS. Example of one level of depth:

```
div.comments > ul.comment-list-wrapper > li.comment-wrapper > ul.comment-list-wrapper ul {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```